# How to pass parameter to the web page from RAD/Delphi application?

Tags: delphi

I am developing an application at RAD Studio on the concept of renew expired licence of application. In this case when client click on yes button I want to redirect them to product website renew licence page with parameters i.e serial no in this case.(I don't want to get any response back like in TIdHTTP).

There are some methodslike shell execute but how can I pass parameter i.e serial no in this case

```
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'iexplore.exe', 'www.mywebsite.com', nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Kindly let me know.

Comment: I don't have iexplore on my machine? What will I do? Why can't I use my preferred browser? Use the default verb, pass nil as the second argument. Pass the URL in the third argument, encoding the parameters in the URL. Don't use ShellExecute though. Use ShellExecuteEx which supports properties error handling.

Comment: `ShellExecute(Handle, nil, 'http://www.mywebsite.com?params_go_here', nil, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);`

Comment: Hi guys, what should be procedure in order to post variable so that parameter are not visible in the URL to user ?

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem finally with the help of guidance received through comments above by David, Remy and search on the net about URLEncode fulction, more detailed search regarding shellexecute function and its parameters. Code snippet is as below

```
nurl: String;

nurl := TIdURI.URLEncode('http://.net/pass?q='+q);

shellexecute(handle,'open', PChar(nurl),nil,nil,0);
```

PChar(nurl) used because it was returning error incompatible type PWideChar and String without PChar